Airflow Connection type doesn't appear
I have a problem with my Airflow 2.9.1. I have it set up using docker. The machine works for me in the .yaml file I have defined
_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:- salesforce}
It downloads the library for me of course, which works, but afterwards manually in the Web UI in connection I can't add and the connection type doesn't show me as “Salesforce”. Where could the problem be?
Tried to find a solution
